# How To start/stop IIS 6.0/7.0 remotely using PowerShell Scripts?

Tags: iis, powershell, remote-control

I have two servers Server A and Server B. I want to stop server A from Server B remotely using Powershell script.

Comment: We need some more information about the configuration of your domain. Are both servers operating in the same domain that a single user account has equivalent permissions on the server?

Comment: Also this question should probably be moved to server fault.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to do this is really with just a command line execution using [PsExec](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/sysinternals/Utilities/PsExec.html). And send over to the machines

IISReset /STOP or /START or /RESTART

So you'd do something like this

```
PsExec \\Server2 -u Administrator -p somePassword IISReset /STOP
```

Just be careful with password management if you go this route or any route that involves some type of admin level account impersonation so that no one can get a plain text copy of the admin password.

Comment: I get error: The term 'PsExec' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...

Comment: @steve that's why there's a link, but the simplest is `choco install sysinternals`

Answer (score 13):

Option 1:

```
iisreset remotepcname /restart
```

Option 2:

```
(Get-Service -ComputerName remotepc -Name 'IISAdmin').stop()
```

Option 3:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotepc -ScriptBlock {iisreset}
```

Comment: All three fail for me. 1) The term 'iisreset' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..., 2) Cannot find any service with service name 'IISAdmin', 3) ...The WinRM client
cannot process the request....

Answer (score 10):

Because you asked for Powershell:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName ServerA -Filter "Name='iisadmin'").InvokeMethod("StopService", $null)
```

Agreed this question should be moved to ServerFault.

Comment: Fails with error: Get-WmiObject : Access is denied.

Answer (score 3):

```
$service = Get-WmiObject -computer 'ServerA' Win32_Service -Filter "Name='IISAdmin'"
$service
$service.InvokeMethod('StopService',$Null)
start-sleep -s 5
$service.InvokeMethod('StartService',$Null)
start-sleep -s 5
$service.State

$service = Get-WmiObject -computer 'ServerB' Win32_Service -Filter "Name='IISAdmin'"
$service
$service.InvokeMethod('StopService',$Null)
start-sleep -s 5
$service.InvokeMethod('StartService',$Null)
start-sleep -s 5
$service.State
```

Comment: Fails with error: Get-WmiObject : Access is denied.

Answer (score 2):

In powershell 2.0, run the following from cmd prompt:

```
invoke-command -computername <yourremoteservername> -scriptblock {iisreset}
```

Comment: Fails with error: ...The WinRM client cannot process the request....

Answer (score 0):

You can use get-wmiobject cmdlt with different NameSpace for different versions of IIS v6 or v7, below pipelining command can be used for such operations in IIS locally or remotely

for IIS v6

```
$srv = "Server Name or IP Address"

$app = "Name of App Pool"

$x = get-wmiobject -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IIsApplicationPool" -ComputerName $srv -Authentication PacketPrivacy | where-object {$_.Name -eq "W3SVC/AppPools/$app"}

$x.Stop()

$x.Start()

for IIS v7

$srv = "Server Name or IP Address"

$app = "Name of App Pool"

$x = Get-WMIObject -Namespace "root\webAdministration" -Class "ApplicationPool" -ComputerName $srv -Authentication PacketPrivacy | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $app}

$x.Stop()

$x.Start()
```

you need to have sufficient account privilege for these operations, event though i prefer to do $x.Recycle() for my websites.